# Cannot switch to a new panel

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to switch a new panel after I clicked  button. I created a panel with two tabs (notebook) and each tab has buttons. These buttons will switch into a new panel when it is clicked. However, I faced some errors. This is my code:

```
import wx

page1 = None;
page2 = None;

# create a new panel
class NewPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, size = (800, 600))
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        button8 = wx.Button(self, label="Button Two", pos=(0, 0))

# the first notebook created on the panel.
class BookOne(wx.Panel): 
    def __init__(self, parent):        
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, size = (800,600))

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Button One", (0, 20), size = (200, 30))
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSwitchPanels1)

    def onSwitchPanels1(self, event):
        if self.page1.IsShown():
           self.SetTitle("Panel")
           self.page1.Hide()
           self.new_panel.Show()
        else:
           self.SetTitle("Panel")
           self.page1.Show()
           self.new_panel.Hide()
        self.Layout()


# second notebook created on the same panel.
class BookTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, size = (800,600))
        #self.mypanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size = (800, 600))

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button7 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Button A", (0, 20), size = (200, 30))
        #button7.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onSwitchPanels7)
        button8 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Button B", (0, 70), size = (200, 30))
        #button8.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onSwitchPanels8)


# the main frame/panel/windows.
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something  = "something";
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,title="My Panel", size=(800, 600))

        # Here we create a panel and a notebook on the panel
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        global page1,page2;

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        page1 = BookOne(nb)
        page2 = BookTwo(nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        nb.AddPage(page1, "Tab One")
        nb.AddPage(page2, "Tab Two")


        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


        self.page1 = BookOne(nb)
        self.page1.Hide()
        self.new_panel = NewPanel(p)
        self.new_panel.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.page1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.new_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        #self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I've tried some solutions but the second panel won't appear after I clicked the button 'Button One'.

Comment: Do you get any error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? if yes then put all error message in question.

Comment: Do you want to create new panel inside tab ? or you want to create next tab ?

Answer (score 0):

First you get error when I click `Button One`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 28, in onSwitchPanels1
AttributeError: 'PageOne' object has no attribute 'page1'
```

---

**EDIT:**

I made some modifications - now it show/hide `tab three` and `tab four`
But I think I didn't understand what you really what to do.

Maybe this code helps you to do what you really need.

Most important part is `.GetParent()` - I use it to get access to elements in main class.

I removed `global` because I think we use classes to not use `globals`

```
import wx
import os

wildcard = "All files (*.*)|*.*"

class PanelThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button8 = wx.Button(self, label="Button Two", pos=(0, 0))

# the first tab created.
class PageOne(wx.Panel): 
    def __init__(self, parent):        
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button One", (0, 20), size = (200, 30))
        button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSwitchPanels1)

    def onSwitchPanels1(self, event):
        if self.GetParent().GetParent().GetParent().page1.IsShown():
           #self.SetTitle("Panel")
           self.GetParent().GetParent().GetParent().page1.Hide()
           self.GetParent().GetParent().GetParent().panel_two.Show()
        else:
           #self.SetTitle("Panel")
           self.GetParent().GetParent().GetParent().page1.Show()
           self.GetParent().GetParent().GetParent().panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()


# second tab created.
class PageTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button7 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button A", (0, 20), size = (200, 30))
        #button7.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onSwitchPanels7)
        button8 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Button B", (0, 70), size = (200, 30))
        #button8.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.onSwitchPanels8)


# the main frame/panel/windows.
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something  = "something";
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,title="My Panel", size=(800, 600))

        # Here we create a panel and a notebook on the panel
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        self.page1a = PageOne(nb)
        self.page2a = PageTwo(nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        nb.AddPage(self.page1a, "Tab One")
        nb.AddPage(self.page2a, "Tab Two")

        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.page1 = PageOne(nb)
        self.page1.Hide()
        self.panel_two = PanelThree(nb)
        self.panel_two.Hide()

        nb.AddPage(self.page1, "Tab Three")
        nb.AddPage(self.panel_two, "Tab Four")

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.page1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        #self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I've got the same error. I've tried some solutions but it still doesn't work. I want to open a new panel after click the button 'Button One'.

Comment: I made some modifications but I don't know if I understand what you really try to do.

Comment: Maybe my question doesn't clear enough for you. I've edited my question. By the way, thanks for your help.

Comment: Mostly I tried to understand your code - and why I'm confused.

Comment: Beside there are three words: panel, tab, page. Sometimes you use it  as words with the same meaning - for example in two lines `# the first tab created.`,`class PageOne(wx.Panel):` - you have `tab` but class has name `page` and it use class `panel`. But then you use that words with different meaning - `I created a panel with two tabs` - probably you means `notebook with two panels (tabs)` (if we use names of classes in code)

Comment: Looks like it is me who confused you. I'm a newbie in python and there are some parts that I don't understand and still working on it. Maybe I should revise my words and codes first before asking any questions here. Thanks in advance.